# Как найти разность между графиками?

Tags: c#

Есть набор из примерно 200 точек. И есть два графика: чёрный построен по всем этим точкам, а зелёный - по четырём. Как построить график погрешности(насколько зелёный отличается от чёрного)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
                x = lower; //нижний предел; здесь строится чёрный график
                while (x <= upper) //верхний предел
                {
                    y = Function(Math.Round(x, 2));
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);
                    x += step; //шаг взятия аргумента
                }
            double[] x_arr = CompMath.Chebyshyov(lower, upper, count); //а вот тут зелёный
                    foreach(double xx in x_arr)
                    {
                        y = Function(Math.Round(xx, 2));
                        chart1.Series[2].Points.AddXY(xx, y);
                    }
```

метод Chebyshyov выбирает узлы в интервале(4 узла в моём случае)
В общем, функция одна, количество аргументов разное

Comment: Посчитайте по массивам исходных данных разности, и соответственно выбранным методом рассчитайте погрешность

Comment: Вы не написали, какием образом эти графики строятся, как хранятся данные, не показали код, не объяснили какого типа приложение, и какая именно библиотека используется для построения. Так же непонятно, интересует вас математика или графика. А вообще берете линию между соседними точками для одного x на обоих графиках. Находите координаты 2 точек для этого x, ну и считаете разницу между двумя точками по y.

Comment: В каждой из 200 точек черного графика, считайте значение зелёного. Разница между значениями - точка нового графика "погрешность/отличие". В чем собственно затруднения?

Comment: Есть определённая функция. И для чёрного графика эта функция рассчитывается для 200 точек, а для зелёного - для 4. Если я пойду по массивам, у меня получится график y=0

Comment: Функция одна. В этом и проблема

Comment: @ATG54 Если у вас есть/найдена **функция** для зелёного, то посчитайте её значение в точках от черного

Comment: Не найдена. А как её найти?

Comment: Добавил код, если интересно)

Comment: @ATG54 полином Лагранжа например, почитайте по аппроксимацию или интерполяцию

Comment: Я Лагранжа уже делал, там получается полная ерунда, а вот это получается правильно, по крайней мере, в методичке так же

Comment: Как описана `Series[2]` - в ней встроена аппроксимация полиномами Чебышёва или что-то другое??

Comment: Да, узлы Чебышёва

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, судя по картинке, зеленый построен из 5 точек. Как минимум потому, что график меняет своё направление движения 4 раза -> следовательно минимум 5 точек (чтобы произошло 1 направление необходимо минимум 2 точки, для 2 направлений (и 1 смены направления) необходимо минимум 3 точки и т.п.).

Далее, вам следует пойти такими путями:

1. Как написал MBo, просто посчитайте разность в каждой точке. Да, скорее всего, для этого нужно будет найти каждую точку у зеленого графика. Далее построить график размера погрешности в зависимости от x, где значениями функции как раз будут разности в каждой точке.
2. Вы можете найти *корреляцию* между 2 графиками - это "мерило" может показать насколько одно соответствует другому, если прям уж грубо говорить (или насколько одно зависит от другого), такие методы иногда применяются в цифровой обработке сигналов для сравнения 2 сигналов (представленных графиком). Коэффициент корреляции принимает значения от -1 до +1. Где +1 вы получите если сравните таким образом один и тот же график (или с незначительными по меркам точности модели и округлений модели). Так вы тоже можете их сравнить

PS: С точки зрения математики про корреляцию тут совсем уж грубо, я старался объяснить "на пальцах", поэтому если хотите разобраться, почитайте литературу, написанную профессионалами, а не комментарии "умников из Интернетов".